# IndexedDB slow when inserting

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios8, indexeddb

I installed iOS 8 on a third generation iPad and tried IndexedDB in Safari. My sample code just adds 1000 objects to an object store.

It works however it is very slow compared to other devices with similar or weaker hardware.

See this snippet for implementation details (IndexedDB seems to be disabled on stackoverflow so the example does not work out of the box - <del>use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5p6mL6m/1/) instead</del>):

Added the snippet to jsbin because jsfiddle raises a SecurityException on iOS device and updated with Deni Spasovskis answer http://jsbin.com/jorohe/1/. The problem still persists.

Original code:

```js
var openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("testdb");

openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "open success<br/>";
 
 var db = event.target.result;
 var trans = db.transaction(["testStore"], (typeof IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY !== "undefined") ? IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE : "readwrite" );
 var store = trans.objectStore("testStore");
 
 var reqClear = store.clear();
 reqClear.onsuccess = function () {
 
  var objectsToAdd = 1000;
  var addedObjects = 0;
  
  var startTime = window.performance.now();
  
  for (var i=0; i<objectsToAdd; i++) {
   (function (pos) {
   var req = store.add({testID: pos, a: "foo", b: "bar"});
   req.onsuccess = function () {
    addedObjects++;
    if (addedObjects >= objectsToAdd) {
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "done adding<br />";
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Took: "+(window.performance.now() - startTime)+"ms<br />";
    }
   }
   req.onerror = function () {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "error adding element:" + req.error + " <br/>";
   }
   })(i);
  }
 }
 reqClear.onerror = function () {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "error clearing store: "+reqClear.error+"<br/>";
 }
};

openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
 var db = event.target.result;
 var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("testStore", { keyPath: "testID" });
 
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "created store<br/>";
};

openRequest.onerror = openRequest.onabort = function () { 
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "error opening db<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```

The iPad took around 6 seconds while Internet Explorer on a HTC Windows Phone 8s (weaker hardware) only took 1,5 seconds and Chrome on a Samsung Galaxy S III (which might be comparable to the iPad) finished the insert in 300 milliseconds.

While I understand that this technology is new on iOS I was not expecting such a harsh performance decrease.

Is there anything wrong with the code or is there any other way to achieve decent performance with IndexedDB on iOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

For optimal performance when batch inserting you shouldn't listen for events on every add statement, instead you should attach to the transaction `oncomplete` and `onerror` events.

I've changed your code a bit and got 15% performance increase (~290ms down from ~340ms) on my phone (nexus 4). But this is still slow when compared to the PC.

The code snippet doesn't work so here is link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5p6mL6m/2/

```js
var openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("testdb");

openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "open success<br/>";
 
 var db = event.target.result;
 var trans = db.transaction(["testStore"], (typeof IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY !== "undefined") ? IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE : "readwrite" );
 var store = trans.objectStore("testStore");
     var startTime;
 trans.oncomplete = function () {
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "finished adding<br />";
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "End time: "+(window.performance.now() - startTime)+"<br />";
    
   }
 var reqClear = store.clear();
 reqClear.onsuccess = function () {
     startTime = window.performance.now();
  var objectsToAdd = 1000;
  var addedObjects = 0;
  
  for (var i=0; i<objectsToAdd; i++) {
   store.add({testID: i, a: "foo", b: "bar"});
   
  }
 }
 reqClear.onerror = function () {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "error clearing store: "+reqClear.error+"<br/>";
 }
};

openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
 var db = event.target.result;
 var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("testStore", { keyPath: "testID" });
 
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "created store<br/>";
};

openRequest.onerror = openRequest.onabort = function () { 
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "error opening db<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer reduced the insert time by about 200ms, but it is still 6 seconds in total. I am not talking about the difference between PC and mobile which is explainable, but the difference between similar mobile devices. It is strange that Android devices perform the insert in about 300ms while it is 6 seconds on iOS devices about 20 times more

Comment: The JS fiddle in this answer does not work on Safari 6.2 on an iMac or iOS8 on an iPad 2. Throws a DOM Error 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy.

Comment: Try the jsbin in the original question. It contains the example code with Deni Spasoviskis improvements and should work on iOS devices

Comment: Marcus what's the speed on Safari on Mac vs Chrome on Mac, if there is a significant difference you can write bug to safari browser?

Comment: I cannot test it on a Mac because I do not own one. Someone else needs to give it a try